# How can a pass a variable value from an external JS jQuery file to a function in a html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, html-table

I have a jQuery created table.
I need to pass a column number when it is clicked to a varaible or function in the a html file.

In the jQuery file I can run (when the header in a table is clicked):

```
thisSheet.delegate(".TimeSheet-colHead","mouseup.umsSheetEvent",function(ev){   

//other non-important code removed
var columnNum = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
console.log('Column: ' + columnNum );
J_timingSubmit2.click();
```

This outputs the correct column number to the console.
The last line clicks a hidden button in the html file which runs the function:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit2").click(function(ev){
```

In the above function if I add the line.

```
console.log('Column: ' + columnNum );
```

It always returns the number 2, no matter what column I click, even if I add above it, the line:

```
var columnNum = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
```

How can I pass the column number to the existing function or another function/variable in the html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Jquery you can use localStorage

```
//set item in storage
localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
// to retrive
localStorage.getItem("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have tried it. I already use this method, the other way around (html file to js file) but for some reason I thought it was limited to one item! I know better now. Thanks again.